# How can I set the displayed increments of the ruler units in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I was following a tutorial related to the construction of a web template using Photoshop. I have found this image that shows the use of the guides:

[image: Photoshop Guides]

I have no problem placing a guide into my canvas, but I have trouble understanding what unit of measurement is used in this case. I think that this uses **pixels**, is that right?

My problem is that if I set the rulers to use pixels in Photoshop, I do not have these ruler increments: 0, 50, 100, 150, and so on... Instead, I have different increments: 0, 20, 40, 60 and so on...

So I have some doubts related to the active unit of measurement. Can I change the displayed increments to have something exactly like the previous image?

Answer (score 1):

The rulers in your image could be pixels, points, percents, millimeters.... there's really no way for us to tell specifically merely by looking at an image. Right-Click/Control-Click directly on one of the rulers to pop up the measurement selector, that will tell you want the rulers are set to and allow you to change them if needed.

Realize that the rulers change based upon zoom level. If you need to more clearly see smaller divisions in the ruler, zoom in on the document.

Because rulers are standard measurement values, there is no way to manually configure their divisions.

If you need manual division, you may want to look at the **Photoshop Preferences** under **Guides, Grids & Slices**. There you can set divisions and subdivisions to a custom value for the Grid. Then merely turn on the Grid in the **View Menu** after setting your division values (`View > Show > Grid`)